# AdMob Native Ad in a SwiftUI project

Tags: swift, swiftui, admob

I'm trying to implement a native ad into a SwiftUI project but I can't figure out how to manage the callout button.
Currently everything is displayed correctly, but I can't find in the documentation how to integrate this.

Here is my class:

```
enum AdStatus {
    case loading, success, failure
}

final class NativeViewController2: NSObject, ObservableObject, GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate, GADNativeAdDelegate {

    @Published var adStatus: AdStatus = .loading
    
    var adLoader: GADAdLoader?
    var nativeAd: GADNativeAd?
    // The ad unit ID.
    let adUnitID = Pub.AdMob.nativeAdUnitId

    
    func loadAd(adStatus: AdStatus){
        self.adStatus = adStatus
        
        let options = GADNativeAdMediaAdLoaderOptions()
        options.mediaAspectRatio = .square
        
        let root = UIApplication
            .shared
            .connectedScenes
            .flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }!.rootViewController
        
        adLoader = GADAdLoader(adUnitID: adUnitID, rootViewController: root!, adTypes: [GADAdLoaderAdType.native], options: [options])
        adLoader?.delegate = self
        adLoader?.load(GADRequest())
    }

    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        // Ajout Cedric -> Set ourselves as the native ad delegate to be notified of native ad events.
        nativeAd.delegate = self
        
        self.nativeAd = nativeAd
        self.adStatus = .success
        print("display Ad -> success")
        
    }
    
    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
        self.adStatus = .failure
        print("display Ad -> failure")
    }
    
    func nativeAds() -> GADNativeAd? {
        self.nativeAd
    }
}
```

and structs to display the ad:

```
struct NativeView: View {
    
    @State var adStatus: AdStatus
    
    @State var nativeViewController: NativeViewController2()

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if nativeViewController.adStatus == .success {
                if let nativeAd = nativeViewController.nativeAds() {
                    NativeAdView2(nativeAd: nativeAd)
                        .frame(height: 140, alignment: .center)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            nativeViewController.loadAd(adStatus: adStatus)
        }
    }
}


struct NativeAdView2: View {
    
    var nativeAd: GADNativeAd
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Pub")
                    .font(.system(size: 11, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .fill(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)))
                    )
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            .padding(.bottom, -10)
            
            HStack {
                Image(uiImage: (nativeAd.icon?.image)!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    //.mask(Circle())
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(nativeAd.headline!)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .font(.body)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .lineSpacing(1)
                    
                    Text(nativeAd.advertiser ?? "Advert")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            
            
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
                //Spacer()
                Text(nativeAd.price ?? "")
                    //.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                //Spacer()
                if let starRating = nativeAd.starRating {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<Int(truncating: starRating), id: \.self) { _ in
                            Image(systemName: "star")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                //Spacer()
                if let cTA = nativeAd.callToAction {
                    Button(action: {
                        // ???????????????
                    }, label: {
                        Text(cTA)
                            //.fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            .padding(.vertical, 5)
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .fill(Color(.systemBlue))
                            )
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                }
            }
            .font(.subheadline)
            
        }
        .modifier(forEachDesign())
        .frame(height: 140, alignment: .center)
        .background(BlurView(style: .dark))
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

Here is what the display of advertising in the app gives:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKNgw.jpg

Thank you for your help

Comment: Just FYI Binding does not work in a class, at least not reliably sometimes you’ll get instances where it appears to work but it relies on a SwiftUI body.

Comment: indeed I replaced by Published (code updated). Thank you. Any idea about a solution to my problem ?

Comment: No, I don’t use native ads. I don’t even know what callout button you are trying to use. I’m sure you’ll get help from someone else.

Comment: I think the only way is to use the interface builder to build the view as mentioned in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/swiftui It's really horrible because I have to learn how to use it from scratch just to implement a native ad in SwiftUI.